# How do I bind my data to my combobox control wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

This my data that I wamt to bind to a `ComboBox` control

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Contact contact = new Contact();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Mr" });
        contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Dr " });
        contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Mis" });
        contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Miss" });
        contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Sir" });

        contact.Genders.Add(new Gender { gender = "Male" });
        contact.Genders.Add(new Gender { gender = "Female" });

        DataContext = contact.Genders;
        DataContext = contact.Titles;

    }
}
```

Comment: Check your formatting, the code sample isn't clear.  Also tell us what you have already tried, what went wrong, what you need help with if you already checked the documentation and didn't find the example you're asking for here

Comment: You are setting `DataContext` of `Window` and overriding it. `ComboBox` is not even in picture here. Why do you expect this code to work?

Comment: I was trying to put the picture of my combobox but I couldn't. All I want to do is bind my data to my combobox as I am coding behind my UI.

Comment: I am a beginner on C# sorry if you do not understand me.

Comment: Do you want to display titles or genders in the ComboBox?

Comment: Yes I want to display.

Comment: titles *or* genders? Which one of them is it?

Comment: Both of them on two comboboxes

Comment: Answer I have been given below is not working for me.

Comment: @StanleyMabunda code below work perfectly, show more of your code.

Comment: Oooh yes it works perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set DataContext property twice, cuz it's the property of your MainWindow class. 
First make Contact object the DataContext for you MainWindow, that's all.
Implement INotifyPropertyChanged for it.

And make bindings in XAML like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Titles}" MaxHeight="20"/>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Genders}" Grid.Column="1"  MaxHeight="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And there's MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
:

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Contact contact;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            contact = new Contact();
            this.DataContext = contact;

            contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Mr" });
            contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Dr " });
            contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Mis" });
            contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Miss" });
            contact.Titles.Add(new Title { title = "Sir" });

            contact.Genders.Add(new Gender { gender = "Male" });
            contact.Genders.Add(new Gender { gender = "Female" });
        }
    }

    public class Contact : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Title> Titles
        {
            get { return _titles; }
            set
            {
                _titles = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Titles));
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Gender> Genders
        {
            get { return _genders; }
            set
            {
                _genders = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Genders));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Title> _titles { get; set; }
        private ObservableCollection<Gender> _genders { get; set; }


        public Contact()
        {
            Titles = new ObservableCollection<Title>();
            Genders = new ObservableCollection<Gender>();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }

    public class Title
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return title;
        }
    }

    public class Gender
    {
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return gender;
        }
    }
```